# Appending a suffix to a term which consists of multiple words

Tags: suffixes

I would like to express the circumstance that a device is something like a cash register, but not quite the same. 
I would like to append the suffix '-like' to do so.

However, I am unsure how to write this down correctly, for 'cash register' are actually two words.

Would I write

> a cash-register-like device.

or rather

> a cash register-like device.

Or neither of them?

Comment: We've had this before; I think the consensus was that the doubly-hyphenated variant caused less confusion, showing that 'cash register' is compound, re-instating a perhaps lost hyphen. However, 'device [rather / somewhat] like a cash register' or 'device resembling / in some ways like a cash register' sound far more natural.

Comment: or perhaps "'cash-register' like device". Could you not rephrase to something along the lines of 'similar to a cash register'? I think the usage of '-like' is adequate in whichever form you choose, provided it is an informal usage, I'm not sure it's usage as a term portrays well in more formal applications. (But this is just opinion really)

Answer (score 3):

Follow the direction of the manual of style you have chosen or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which prescribes that *-like* formations are solid (no hyphens) -- catlike -- except

1. with proper names, *Starbucks-like* coffee shop,
2. words ending in *ll*, a *gill-like* slit,
3. compound words, a *cash-register-like* device.

Comment: Which subsets (solid ...) of compound words? Does CMOS include an open-form to hyphenated-form conversion (as with cash register ==> cash-register-like)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd regard *cash-register-like* as clumsy, or some kind of adjective fetish. :)

A device like a cash-register.

large-hadron-collider-like device.